# .Net MAUI Picker inside list-item keep opening option dialog automatically after selecting an option from picker options

Tags: .net, maui, picker

When using a picker inside list item its item selection doesn't work normally.
when selecting an option it get closed but again opens the selection dialog automatically.

```
  <Picker Title="Select an option">
                                            <Picker.Items>
                                                <x:String>Option 1</x:String>
                                                <x:String>Option 2</x:String>
                                                <x:String>Option 3</x:String>
                                            </Picker.Items>
                                        </Picker>
```

Comment: What os are you testing this on. Do you have any additional code about selection?

Comment: Hello, cannot reproduce this issue based on the description. Could you please share a  MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example)?  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo and it worked well on my end.

In this demo, I put a Picker in the datatemplate and bind the ItemsSource property to Items collection in viewmodel. You may have a try.

```
<ListView x:Name="mylist" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout> 
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                      <Picker Title="Select an option" HeightRequest="50">
                                <Picker.Items>
                                    <x:String>Option 1</x:String>
                                    <x:String>Option 2</x:String>
                                    <x:String>Option 3</x:String>
                                </Picker.Items>
                            </Picker>
                    </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

For more info, you could refer to [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview)

Hope it helps!